# Web.config runtime/legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy setting not working

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net

I currently working in a solution in Visual Studio 2017 that runs in IIS 10.0.14393, the main project of the solution is C# in .net 4.6 framework, but it also references managed and native C++ projects.

I need to catch memory access violation exceptions thrown by the native C++ code in the C# code,  for that if I use the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute in specific methods it work, but I need to do it over the whole project in a global way. To do that the documentation says that using  element in the web.config is enough to be able to catch those exceptions in C#. I added the element in my web.config:

```
  <runtime>
    <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
```

But this didn't change any behavior in the solution, I tried multiple ways of adding it, but I had the same result.
I researched on different forums to see if someone had the same issue, and what I found was that another person had the same issue but no answer...

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4fa37186-79e7-4270-92b7-afe7e3e15c79/does-webconfig-support-runtimelegacycorruptedstateexceptionspolicy?forum=clr

https://forums.asp.net/t/2017975.aspx?Problem+with+web+config+and+runtime+legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy+setting

Any clue of what can I do to use this?, or any alternative to catch native exceptions in managed code globally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally what I got from asking around is that if legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy is not in applicationHost.config the web.config don't support it.

So, another alternative to make this work globally that worked for me is adding the setting to the machine.config.

So just adding:

```
<runtime>
  <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
</runtime>
```

to the **machine.config** file
(for 32 bits *%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[version]\config\machine.config* or for 64 *%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64[version]\config\machine.config*)